# Filtering dataframe using subset delivers wrong entries

Tags: r, filter, subset

I've a simple problem within R using subset. It might be obvious, but im working here the last two hours without finding a solution.

My code as follows:

```
##I set a dataframe with 3 rows. the first row contains a unique ID (index), the second    and third contain "dates"
datensatz_Start_End <- read.csv ("Daten/Daten_RequestTable(Test4)_Start_End.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec= ",")

index <- (datensatz_Start_End[,1])
BDATE <- as.Date(datensatz_Start_End[,2], format="%d.%m.%Y")
TIME <- as.Date(datensatz_Start_End[,3], format="%d.%m.%Y")

dataset_Start_End.frame <- data.frame(index,BDATE,TIME)
```

My goal is to get all entries, whiche TIME is less than a specific value.

The Solution as follows:

```
subset(datensatz_Start_End.frame,datensatz_Start_End.frame$"TIME" < "2013-01-01"))
```

This should (at least in my opinion) work.

The problem is, that the delivered results are less than expected. E.g. for my dataset the function within R delivers ~1000 entries and Excel (via a simple filter request) nearly 2000.

Any Suggestions? Thanx in Advance!

Georg

Comment: Very hard to help you without your data. Can you at least `dput(head(datensatz_Start_End.frame))` and I would write the subset like this : `subset(datensatz_Start_End.frame, TIME < as.Date("2013-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"))`

Answer (score 0):

Should be:
subset(datensatz_Start_End.frame, TIME < as.Date("2013-01-01"))